# Publisher actions not showing after navigateToFeed

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, chatter

After using sforce.one.navigateToFeed() to direct the user to a record feed, they can see the feed, post comments on existing feed items and like them too but they don't have the publisher actions bar to create a new post.

When opening the feed via a desktop browser, you can create a new post and use all the other options (attachments, polls, etc) so it's not like they have insufficient privileges to do so.

If in Salesforce1 the user views their full chatter feed or opens a users profile record, they have the publisher actions as expected.

Has this got something to do with the fact we are navigating away from a Visualforce page or am I missing some configuration?